# How to store a java application within a website?

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, server

I am working on an assignment for my co-op job placement starting this summer. I have created a basic java GUI, called Slots.java, which is a basic slot machine. I want to be able to "store", for lack of a better term, the entirety of the application on a website so that it has zero dependence on my computer. If I were to delete this application and code from my computer, it should still run fine and indepently from the website. In the future I would also like to have the record the date of each time the game is played and whether or not it results in a win stored within a database, so server communication is going to be a big aspect of it. I also need to take into account that the application utilizes image files, and how these would be stored. I have researched JSPs and the option of converting the application into an applet, but these both seem to still rely on the application being hosted on my computer. This is a lengthy question, but I am lost as my background is primarily in java application devlopment at school. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is my java code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Slots extends JFrame
                   implements ActionListener
{
  private JLabel message;
  private JButton spin;
  private JButton newGame;
  private JCheckBox hold1;
  private JCheckBox hold2;
  private JCheckBox hold3;
  private JPanel topPanel;
  private JLabel imageLabel1;
  private JLabel imageLabel2;
  private JLabel imageLabel3;
  private JPanel buttonsPanel;
  private JPanel messagePanel;
  private ImageIcon club;
  private ImageIcon spade;
  private ImageIcon diamond;
  private ImageIcon heart;
  private Random generator;
  private boolean checked1;
  private boolean checked2;
  private boolean checked3;
  private int spinCounter;
  private int spinsLeft;
  private int cfollow;
  private int sfollow;
  private int dfollow;
  private int hfollow;
  private int total;
  private int num1;
  private int num2;
  private int num3;

//********************Constructor********************

  public Slots()
  {
    message = new JLabel("Click Spin to begin");
    spin = new JButton("Spin");
    newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    hold1 = new JCheckBox("Hold");
    hold2 = new JCheckBox("Hold");
    hold3 = new JCheckBox("Hold");
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    imageLabel1 = new JLabel();
    imageLabel2 = new JLabel();
    imageLabel3 = new JLabel();
    buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    messagePanel = new JPanel();
    club = new ImageIcon("Club.png");
    spade = new ImageIcon("Spade.png");
    diamond = new ImageIcon("Diamond.png");
    heart = new ImageIcon("Heart.png");
    generator = new Random();
    checked1 = false;
    checked2 = false;
    checked3 = false;
    spinCounter = 0;
    spinsLeft = 3;
    cfollow = 5;
    sfollow = 50;
    dfollow = 500;
    hfollow = 5000;
    total = 0;
    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;
    num3 = 0;


    this.setTitle("");
    Container pane = this.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    topPanel.add(imageLabel1);
    topPanel.add(imageLabel2);
    topPanel.add(imageLabel3);
    topPanel.add(hold1);
    topPanel.add(hold2);
    topPanel.add(hold3);
    pane.add(topPanel, "North");

    buttonsPanel.add(spin);
    buttonsPanel.add(newGame);
    pane.add(buttonsPanel, "Center");

    messagePanel.add(message);
    pane.add(messagePanel, "South");

    spin.addActionListener(this);
    newGame.addActionListener(this);

    this.setSlots();
  }



//********************setSlots()*********************

  public void setSlots()
  {
   int num = 0;
   int rand1 = generator.nextInt(4);
   int rand2 = generator.nextInt(4);
   int rand3 = generator.nextInt(4);
   if(getSelected1() == false){
       if(rand1 == 0)
         {
         imageLabel1.setIcon(club);
         num1 = 5;
         }
       else if(rand1 == 1)
         {
         imageLabel1.setIcon(spade);
         num1 = 50;
         }
       else if(rand1 == 2)
         {
         imageLabel1.setIcon(diamond);
         num1 = 500;
         }
       else
         {
         imageLabel1.setIcon(heart);
         num1 = 5000;
         }
         }

    if(getSelected2() == false){
       if(rand2 == 0)
         {
         imageLabel2.setIcon(club);
         num2 = 5;
         }
       else if(rand2 == 1)
         {
         imageLabel2.setIcon(spade);
         num2 = 50;
         }
       else if(rand2 == 2)
         {
         imageLabel2.setIcon(diamond);
         num2 = 500;
         }
       else
         {
         imageLabel2.setIcon(heart);
         num2 = 5000;
         }
         }
    if(getSelected3() == false){
       if(rand3 == 0)
         {
         imageLabel3.setIcon(club);
         num3 = 5;
         }
       else if(rand3 == 1)
         {
         imageLabel3.setIcon(spade);
         num3 = 50;
         }
       else if(rand3 == 2)
         {
         imageLabel3.setIcon(diamond);
         num3 = 500;
         }
       else
         {
         imageLabel3.setIcon(heart);
         num3 = 5000;
         }
         }
         }

//********************getSelected1()********************

  public boolean getSelected1()
  {
  if(hold1.isSelected())
    {
    checked1 = true;
    }
    else
    {
    checked1 = false;
    }
    return checked1;
  }

//********************getSelected2()********************

  public boolean getSelected2()
  {
  if(hold2.isSelected())
    {
    checked2 = true;
    }
    else
    {
    checked2 = false;
    }
    return checked2;
  }

//********************getSelected3()********************

  public boolean getSelected3()
  {
  if(hold3.isSelected())
    {
    checked3 = true;
    }
    else
    {
    checked3 = false;
    }
    return checked3;
  }

//********************pressNewGame()********************
  public void pressNewGame()
    {
     checked1 = false;
     checked2 = false;
     checked3 = false;
     spinCounter = 0;
     spinsLeft = 3;
     this.setSlots();
     message.setText("Click Spin to begin");
     total = 0;
     num1 = 0;
     num2 = 0;
     num3 = 0;
     while(total == 15 || total == 150 || total == 1500 || total == 15000)
          {
          this.setSlots();
          }
    }

//********************end()********************
  public void end()
    {
      int uselessInt = 1;
    }

//********************isWin()********************
  public String isWin()
    {
    String gameOver = "Game Over";
    String winner = "We have a winner!";
    if(total == 15 || total == 150 || total == 1500 || total == 15000)
      {
      return winner; 
      }
    else
      return gameOver;
    }


//********************actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)******************** 

  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
  {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if(source == newGame)
      {
      this.pressNewGame();
      }
    else if(source == spin)
      {
      while(spinCounter >= 0)
      {
      this.setSlots();
      spinCounter++;
      spinsLeft = spinsLeft - 1;
      break;
      }
      if(spinCounter <= 2)
        {
        message.setText("Spins left: " + spinsLeft + " Score: " + total);
        }
      else
        {
      message.setText(this.isWin());
      }
      }
    else
      {
      this.end();      
      }
  }    

//********************main(String[] args)********************  

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Slots frame = new Slots();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Anything, i.e. any machine, has to execute the code, so you'll have to depend on your local machine or the server's OS, Java runtime environment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is a little more complex than what you will get out of SO. You need to research servlet containers like Apache Tomcat.

Basically you need a webserver to run your code.

Since this is a AWT app, the only way to represent it would be to convert it to an applet. That would be saved up on a some hosted site and embedded into an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

---

## Java App

You have two choices for running Java code delivered from a web server to a user’s machine: Java Applet, and Java Web Start.

In both cases, the downloaded Java code executes locally on the user’s computer. So both of these technologies require the user’s local computer to have installed a Java implementation (a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)).

### Java Applet

[Java Applet technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) delivers an executable Java app to the user via a web browser. The applet then uses [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java))/[AWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) or [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) to present a [user-interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) within a [web browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser). This approach has fallen out of mainstream use due to a variety of factors including security concerns.

### Java Web Start

[Java Web Start technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) enables a Java app to be downloaded to the user’s computer and then executed locally as a standalone app. ‘Standalone’ means no web browser needed while the app runs. Again, Java Swing/AWT/JavaFX can be used to present a user-interface.

JWS was developed as an alternative to Java Applets, to address some of the concerns including security. JWS continues to be a viable option.

---

## Web App

More common is a [Web Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) (or web app). The basic idea is that business logic and data storage executes on the server while the user-interface is presented remotely via a web browser using only common web technologies.

[Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) technology is often used on the “back-end” (the server side) to handle the incoming requests and outgoing responses from/to the web browser. [JavaServer Pages (JSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) is one of many available frameworks layered on top of Servlet technology.

Java Servlet apps execute within any of a number of [Servlet containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) that implement the [Servlet spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369). Popular examples include [Tomcat by Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), [Jetty by Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)), [Glassfish by Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish), [WildFly by Red Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly), and many more.

## Frameworks

Most frameworks that help you build a web app work directly with web technologies such as: [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model),[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), [Web Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Web_Components&redirect=no), [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). You have a myriad of frameworks to choose from, which I'll not list here. Many are written in Java, and many in other languages.

### Vaadin

I am know of one different kind of framework that uses pure Java to build a web app while masking that alphabet-soup of web technologies: [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin).

You do all your programming in Java, Vaadin then generates the needed HTML/CSS/JavaScript to render a user-interface within the browser. As your use clicks buttons and enters data the server-side Java app is notified. Your business logic code written in Java can respond, altering the data represented in the user-interface, and Vaadin updates the display of the user-interface within the web browser.

I know of one other similar technology to write and run web apps server-side while masking all those web technologies: [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com/), Web Edition. You can deploy to your own server or a [Xojo Cloud server](http://www.xojo.com/cloud/). Xojo uses its own programming language rather than Java but is otherwise quite similar in concept to Vaadin.